# jsf+jpa+eclipselink (eclipse juno)

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jsf-2.2, eclipse-juno

i use jpa (eclipse link) when i test my class main to add data to my table i get this error

```
[EL Info]: 2014-07-18 22:41:55.274--ServerSession(22745079)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486 [EL Info]: connection: 2014-07-18 22:41:55.637--ServerSession(22745079)--    
file:/C:/Users/toshiba/workspaceV2/login/build/classes/_login login successful
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:  Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:77)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
at dao.Comptesdao.ajouterComptedao(Comptesdao.java:17)
at test.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

do you have any idea

Comment: Its really difficult to tell without any code. Have you looked through some of these questions? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjpa%5D+%22No+transaction+is+currently+active%22

Comment: this the code public class Comptesdao {
 public static EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("login");
 public static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
 public static EntityTransaction tx= em.getTransaction();
 
 public void ajouterComptedao (Compte compte){
  if(tx.isActive())
  tx.begin();
  em.persist(compte);
  tx.commit();
 
}